# R {xml_node} to plain text while preserving the tags?

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

I'd like to do exactly what `xml2::xml_text()` or `rvest::html_text()` do but preserve the tags instead of replacing e.g. `<br>` with `\n`. The objective is to e.g. scrape a web page, extract the nodes I want, and store the plain HTML in a variable, much like `write_html()` would store it in a file.

How can I do this?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I am aware, but here I'm asking a very general question and thus believe the description I provided should suffice. The solution I'm looking for is a single function already implemented in `xml2`, only without discarding the tags, or what another function does, only with output to another variable instead of an external file.

Comment: So you want to keep the XML as a string with no parsing? Why can't you just read it as a string? Or do you want to traverse/modify the tree with `xml2` and then get the output of specific parts as a raw, unparsed string?

Comment: @divibisan Indeed. Because the data structure is a list with external pointers and I don't know how to convert that to a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ironically, it turns out that `as.character()` works just fine.

Therefore:

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("http://stackoverflow.com")

res <– html %>%
         html_node("h1") %>%
         as.character()

> res

[1] "<h1 class=\"-title\">Learn, Share, Build</h1>"
```

This is the desired output in my current use case.

On the other hand, for comparison if one needs to strip the tags:

```
res <- html %>%
         html_node("h1") %>%
         html_text()

> res
[1] "Learn, Share, Build"
```